# How to add on_press to change the screen in python using kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have defined my screens in .kv file, and I can access them without any problem when using ie. on_release: app.root.current = 'main' in .kv.
But I have a problem when Buttons are created dynamically in python, what is equivalent to on_release: app.root.current = 'main' in python? Because I cant make it recognize app.root.

Comment: If you post the relevant parts of your code and explain what you've tried, you might get a quicker response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the current `App` in Python by calling `App.get_running_app()`. So, in other words:

```
from kivy.app import App
def change_screen(*args):
    App.get_running_app().root.current = 'main'

from kivy.uix.button import Button
btn = Button(text='abc')
btn.bind(on_press=change_screen)
```

Comment: I would give you a vote up but I'm too young on Stackoverflow. Sry. And yes. it worked flawlessly.